# Convert object field to date and the also the display format of the date

Tags: python, dataframe

I Have a Dataframe with 2 columns Object like that:

```
id                  object
date                object

+------+-----------------+  
|  ID  |      DATE       |
+------+-----------------+
|   1      01/10/2000    |
|   2      09/03/2005    |
|   3    1 January 2020  |
|   4     "21/08/1995"   |
|   5     27 April 2020  |
+------------------------+
```

I would like to convert the dates in the same format dd/mm/yyyy

I tried to use

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])
```

and this

```
df['DATE'].astype("datetime")
```

But i got this errpr :
TypeError: data type 'datetime' not understood

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes are throwing off the datetime conversion for `"21/08/1995"`  You need to get rid of those before converting.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
                  'DATE':['01/10/2000','09/03/2005','1 January 2020','"21/08/1995"', '27 April 2020']})


df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'].str.strip('"')).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print(df)
```

Output

```
   ID        DATE
0   1  10/01/2000
1   2  03/09/2005
2   3  01/01/2020
3   4  21/08/1995
4   5  27/04/2020
```

Comment: Thank you for the explication